# Buttons conflict in jquery navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a web app and I have to buttons in header; Share and Options. When cliking on a button its related content comes down and it comes back up when the button is clicked again. Both buttons work properly. However, if  the user is to click share button and then click options button without closing Share content the content for Options opens below share content.

I want to only display content for one button at a time. If the user is to click on a button when the other isn't collapsed it should collapse it first.

I'm not so experience with jquery and I'm not sure how to fix this one.

Also if you think I could optimize my code on any way I will apreciate the advice.

Thank you..

```
  $('.pull_box_share_triger').click(function() {
        if(!collapsed){  
            var h = document.getElementById('share_box').Height;
            $('#share_box').animate({ height : h+'px' });
            $('#share_link_box').css({ display:'inline-block'});
            $(".overlay").css({ display:'block'});
            $(".pull_box_share_triger").css({ background:'#ffffff' });
            $('#share_social_box').css({ display:'inline-block'});
            $('.share_button').css({ display : 'inline-block'});
        } else {
            $('#share_box').animate({height: 'auto'});
            $('#share_link_box').css({ display:'none'});
            $(".overlay").css({ display : 'none'});
            $(".pull_box_share_triger").css({ background:'#f2f2f2'});
            $('#share_social_box').css({ display:'none'});
            $('.share_button').css({ display : 'none' });
        }
        collapsed = !collapsed;
    });

    $('.pull_box_option_triger').click(function() {
        if(!collapsed){ 
            var h = document.getElementById('options_box').Height;
            $('#options_box').animate({ height : h+'px' });
            $(".overlay").css({ display:'block'});
            $(".pull_box_option_triger").css({ background:'#ffffff' });
            $(".options_content").css({ display:'inline-block'});
        } else {
            $('#options_box').animate({height: 'auto'});
            $(".overlay").css({ display : 'none'});
            $(".pull_box_option_triger").css({ background:'#f2f2f2'});
            $(".options_content").css({ display:'none'});
        }
        collapsed = !collapsed;
    });
```

Comment: you should make a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make two seperate function to hide share and option content and call then in the click of buttons so as to hide them first.

```
$('.pull_box_share_triger').click(function() {
        hideOption();
        if(!collapsed){  
            var h = document.getElementById('share_box').Height;
            $('#share_box').animate({ height : h+'px' });
            $('#share_link_box').css({ display:'inline-block'});
            $(".overlay").css({ display:'block'});
            $(".pull_box_share_triger").css({ background:'#ffffff' });
            $('#share_social_box').css({ display:'inline-block'});
            $('.share_button').css({ display : 'inline-block'});
        } else {
             hideShare();
        }
        collapsed = !collapsed;
    });

    $('.pull_box_option_triger').click(function() {
hideShare();
        if(!collapsed){ 
            var h = document.getElementById('options_box').Height;
            $('#options_box').animate({ height : h+'px' });
            $(".overlay").css({ display:'block'});
            $(".pull_box_option_triger").css({ background:'#ffffff' });
            $(".options_content").css({ display:'inline-block'});
        } else {
               hideOption();
            }
        collapsed = !collapsed;
    });

   function hideShare()
{
  $('#share_box').animate({height: 'auto'});
            $('#share_link_box').css({ display:'none'});
            $(".overlay").css({ display : 'none'});
            $(".pull_box_share_triger").css({ background:'#f2f2f2'});
            $('#share_social_box').css({ display:'none'});
            $('.share_button').css({ display : 'none' });

}

function hideOption()
{
 $('#options_box').animate({height: 'auto'});
            $(".overlay").css({ display : 'none'});
            $(".pull_box_option_triger").css({ background:'#f2f2f2'});
            $(".options_content").css({ display:'none'});

}
```